# Embedded YouTube video doesn't stop in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

Few topics on this but no answers for me.

Embedding youtube video in a overlay div:

```
   <div id="blanket" style="display:none;">
     </div>
        <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Close</a>     
        <iframe width="480" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G5AuItKv?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>                                       
        </div>
```

On firefox when I close the window the video stops, but not in chrome or internet explorer.

Is there some simple javascript I can use to stop it when the user clicks Close?

TIA

Edit:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ytplayer.stop()">Close</a>

 <iframe width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/e/PE1il5znICA?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>


 <script type="text/javascript">
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
}

function stop() {
  if (ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.stopVideo();
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube has a javascript api that you can enable so as to stop the video. To enable the api add this parameter: `&enablejsapi=1` to the end of your src url and now you can access the player through javascript. First you need to get the player reference:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("nameofplayer");
}
```

and now you have the ability to stop the video with the following function:

```
function stop() {
  if (ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.stopVideo();
  }
}
```

Just make a call to `stop();` inside the onclick function for close.

All the youtube javascript api info is located [here](https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html).

Comment: On further inspection iframe youtube api is slightly different. Please take a look [here](https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html#Loading_a_Video_Player) for more information on how to access the player via javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in HTML5. Iframe doesn't work with Youtube API, You must generate object with enable JavaScript api.

Try change:

```
<iframe width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/e/PE1il5znICA?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/e/PE1il5znICA?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer","ytplayer", "480", "390", "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

Exemple:

First add the div to html:

```
<div id="ytplayer">
<p>You need Flash player and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</p>
</div>
```

Then add script to create object and add stop function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId){ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer");}
         var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };var atts = { id: "ytplayer" };


         swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/e/videoID?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer","ytplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

         function stop() {if (ytplayer) {ytplayer.stopVideo();}}
    </script>
```

Work for me.